# c++ program infinite run on root server not possible

Tags: c++, process, infinite

my proggram is running on a root server and has an infinite while loop inside`while(true){...}`.

I run this c++ program as a deamon process from the terminal while I am logged in with ssh `./my_program.cpp &`.

It keeps running fine for hours, even if I am logged of from ssh and going home. The next morning it's just gone.

Can somebody give me a hint? I tought about memory violation, but my program do not collect much memory over time :-( Also the load of the cpu is not mentionable :-(

Any hint would be great. Thank you and have a great day.

Comment: Log the activity of your program.

Comment: Do  you need `nohup`?  [I know you said you could log off, but that doesn't seem likely given your command.]

Comment: On top of logging any activity, have you tried running the program as a non-daemon (i.e. just normally in the foreground) and waiting for it to crash to see what it might say? `memory violation, but my program do not collect much memory over time` .. `int* a = 0; std::cout << *a << std::endl;` is a memory violation and uses `sizeof(int*)` (which is typically 4-8 bytes) .. any and all information can help in debugging the problem :)